# How to insert leading zero in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, insert

This is the code for selecting with leading zeros:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,Asset_No),6) 
  FROM schemaAsset.SystemDefined
```

How can I insert a value to the column Asset_no with leading zeros?

Example is I am only inserting "1" to the column Asset_no, but in the code, it will insert "000001". And also when I insert two digits like 26, it will insert as "000026". The length does not change. Is this possible in SQL Server?

Comment: From where? SQL or a server-side language?

Comment: What data type is `Asset_No`? [Why are you using `VARCHAR` without a length? Please stop doing that.](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length.aspx)

Comment: I need from SQL sir, Thanks

Comment: @AaronBertrand yes it is varchar. I'm a newbie in SQL, ok sir I will stop using varchar without length, thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way to do this is with an `INSTEAD OF` trigger.

```
USE tempdb;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever
(
  Asset_No VARCHAR(6)
);
GO

CREATE TRIGGER dbo.fix_whatever
ON dbo.whatever
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  INSERT dbo.whatever(Asset_No /*, other columns */)
    SELECT RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), Asset_No), 6)
      /*, other columns */
    FROM inserted;
END
GO

INSERT dbo.whatever(Asset_No) SELECT '22';
GO

SELECT Asset_No FROM dbo.whatever;
GO
```

Results:

```
Asset_No
--------
000022
```

Comment: Ok sir I will try this thanks. By the way I will search the function of INSTEAD OF in google, but can I have an explanation from you sir? you explanation might be more helpful than google, thanks

Comment: Wow this code works for me, I just change the name of database. Thank you for this sir! :)

Comment: An [instead of trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179288(v=sql.105).aspx) allows you to look at the data being inserted/updated/deleted *before* it happens, so that you can do things like manipulate the data or even cancel the statement. Some folks will tell you that there is no use for instead of triggers but they absolutely have a place - they are less resource intensive than an after trigger, especially in cases where you have to roll back. That said, this trigger should only be used if you can't modify the insert statement directly, which is how I read your question.

Comment: Ahh, so the instead of trigger is really helpful for situations like this. Yes sir your right I can't directly modify my insert statement. Thank you for explaining it clearly sir :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to do the padding in SQL Server, you can do something like this with your INSERT statement:

```
DECLARE @Asset_no INT = 12;

INSERT INTO schemaAsset.SystemDefined (Asset_no)
  SELECT RIGHT('00000'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@Asset_No),6)
```

Comment: this might be helpful sir, but how can I declare the variable @Asset_No?

Answer (score 1):

The script below allows you to populate a column with numbers for every row in the table. This will give you numbers starting at 2000. The first entry would be 0002000.

```
Declare @id varchar(15)  
set @id = '1999'  
update sometable  
set @id = id = replace(STR(@id + 1,7),' ', '0')  
go
```

Answer (score -2):

For Oracle:

lpad(cast(NUMERIC_VAR as VARCHAR2(5 BYTE)),5,'00000')

Comment: OP is asking about SQL Server, which doesn't have `LPAD`.